# How to order items in a list of dictionaries

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-order-by

I Would like to return children and grandchildren records(i.e. itemNo) in the order they are updated to database. Below query sorts record by itemNo ASC (by default). I believe sorting by Timestamp, will return records in the same order they are updated.

I tried adding Timestamp as below but doesn't work as expected.

Query to return children and grandChildren:

```
public async Task<List<Child>> GetChild(string parentItemNo)
{
           return await DbContext.Items
                .Where(x => x.ItemNo== parentItemNo)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Children.OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).Select(c => new Child
                    {
                        ItemNo = c.ItemNo,
                        ItemName = c.ItemName,  
                        Timestamp = c.Timestamp,
                        GrandChildItemNos = c.Children.OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).Select(gc => 
                           new GrandChild 
                           { 
                              ItemNo = gc.ItemNo, 
                              ItemName = gc.ItemName,
                              Timestamp = gc.Timestamp,
                           })  
                    })).ToListAsync();       // may i know how iadd orderBy here
 }
```

Below is how my responseData look:

```
[
    {"itemNo":"1111","itemName":"A1111", "timestamp":"AAAAAoc5I/o=", "grandChildSerialNos":[]}, 
    {"itemNo":"2222","itemName":"B2222"," "timestamp":"AAAAAoc5I/s=", "grandChildSerialNos":[]},
    {"itemNo":"3333","itemName":"C3333", "timestamp":"AAAAAoc5I/0=", "grandChildSerialNos": 
         [
             {"itemNo":"1234","itemName":"CH1234"..}, 
             {"itemNo":"5678","itemName":"CH5678"...}
         ]
    },      
    {"itemNo":"4444","itemName":"D4444", "timestamp":"AAAAAoc5I/4=" "grandChildSerialNos":[]}
   {"itemNo":"5555","itemName":"E5555", "timestamp":"AAAAAoc5I/w=" "grandChildSerialNos":[]}
]
```

I want responseData to return ItemNo "5555" before "3333" & "4444" (as "5555" was updated before 3333 & 4444). But response is not returned in that order.  I want 'ItemNo' to be sorted by 'Timestamp' instead of ascending order.

Model class as below:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string itemNo { get; set; }  
    public string itemName { get; set; } 
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public string ItemNo {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ItemNo {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}   
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GrandChild> GrandChildItemNos {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: what is your expected response based on responseData ? ordered by ``ItemNo``?

Comment: Yes ItemNo. Would like to order records(i.e. ItemNo) in the order they are updated to database. I believe sorting by Timestamp, will return children and grandChildren in the same order they are added or updated. I want responseData to return itemNo "4444" first, if that was updated before itemNo "1111". Instead of sorting by ascending order.

Comment: ``want responseData to return itemNo "4444" first, if that was updated before itemNo "1111". Instead of sorting by ascending order.`` but in your child or grandchild model there is no timestamp to detect which one was updated first?

Comment: Have added Timestamp to both child and granchild model as suggested (pls check above). Couldnt  get orderBy to work. May I know where do we add orderBy in the query. Should I be using orderBy twice (One for child and another for grandchild) ? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
await DbContext.Items.Where(x => x.ItemNo == parentItemNo)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).Select(c => new Child
                {
                    ItemNo = c.ItemNo,
                    ItemName = c.ItemName,
                    Timestamp = c.Timestamp,
                    GrandChildItemNos = c.GrandChildItemNos.OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).Select(gc =>
                          new GrandChild
                          {
                              ItemNo = gc.ItemNo,
                              ItemName = gc.ItemName,
                              Timestamp = gc.Timestamp,
                          })
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you.  Please check my updated responseData above. It still sorts only by itemNo ASC. Not by timestamp. ItemNo "5555"  was updated before "3333" and "4444". But response is not returned in that order.

Comment: Can you see the translated t-sql that EF generated? if not please add this ``"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"`` to ``LogLevel`` in appsettings.json

Comment: Pls find above the t-sql

Comment: Move only one parenthesis: `.SelectMany(x => x.Children)` and `}).ToListAsync()`. The trick is that the ordering must take place after `SelectMany` has produced one flat list of children.